# VBA: Определить количество столбцов матрицы, в которых есть только один ноль

Tags: visual-basic

Помогите пожалуйста! 
Условия задачи: матрица 10х10 должна быть создана при помощи DataGridView. 
Определить количество столбцов, в которых есть только один ноль.

Вот что у меня получилось:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click 
   Dim i, j, n, k As Integer 
   n = A.Rows.Count - 1 
   k = 0 
   For j = 0 To 9 
     If A(j, i).Value = 0 Then 
        k = k + 1 
     End If 
   Next 
   TextBox1.Text = k 
End Sub
```

Правильно или нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас неверный код. 
Надо переписать примерно так:

```
l=0
For i = 0 to 9
   k=0
   For j = 0 To 9      
      If A(j, i).Value = 0 Then
         k = k + 1      
      End If    
   Next j
   if(k=1)then
     l=l+1
   end if
Next i
TextBox1.Text = l
```

Comment: Вы мой спаситель! Огромное спасибо.

Comment: @KathyKate 

  1. Если ответ устраивает вас нажмите на галочку с левой стороны от ответа. В форуме есть понятие % принятых вопросов, так вот если он низкий, то вам могут просто перестать отвечать
  2. В следующий раз яснее формулируйте свои вопросы - в этот раз я отредактировал, в следующий раз не буду.